# Select options value and text to JSON format

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json

How can i convert select options elements to JSON text.

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

I want to set options belong to select which is not runat=server to the

And I want to split string to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean you want something like this?

```
{ select : [ {option: {value:1, text:"First"}},
             {option: {value:2, text:"Second"}},
             {option: {value:3, text:"Third"}},
             {option: {value:4, text:"Fourth"}}
           ]
}
```

You can parse and stringify any object in Javascript with [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). First you need to build up your object. You can do something like this:

```
var selectJson = {};
selectJson.select = new Array();
var select = document.getElementById("mySelectId");

for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
   var option = select.options[i];
   var optionJson = {};
   optionJson.option = {value: option.value, text: option.text};
   selectJson.select.push(optionJson);
}
```

Then use the stringifier to convert it into a JSON string.